# How to get range value from string using RegEx on Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, range

I want to get range values using RegEx on Javascript so that when I use `.match` it would return the values. I've use `-` or `~` as range operator.

My current regex is `/(\-?\d+)(?:\-|\~)(\-?\d+)/` but this will not return the number with decimal value.

**Successful** get:

- `"5-10"` should return `["5-10", "5", "10"]`
- `"-5-10"` should return `["-5-10", "-5", "10"]`
- `"-5--10"` should return `["-5-10", "-5", "-10"]`

**Failed** to get:

- `"5.1-10"` should return `["5.1-10", "5.1", "10"]`
- `"-5.1-10"` should return `["-5.1-10", "-5.1", "10"]`
- `"-5.1--10"` should return `["-5.1-10", "-5.1", "-10"]`
- `"-5.1--10.2"` should return `["-5.1-10", "-5.1", "-10.2"]`

Comment: Regex might not be the best tool for this.  May we ask why you aren't storing the separate values in separate variables?  I see a normalization problem here.

Comment: We did not store it separately because we have a lot of expressions need to validate. Other expressions are `>=Number`, `>Number`, `'<= Number'`, and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^(-?\d+\.?\d*?)[-~](-?\d+\.?\d*?)$/
```

You need to capture the first digit which may have negative sign `-` and decimal with digit `.digit`. Then separate by either hyphen `-` or tilde `~`, finally capture the second digit with the same manner as the first one.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Davіd i've added explanation :)

Comment: Thank you!. I've used `/^(-?\d+\.?\d*?)(?:\-|\~)(-?\d+\.?\d*?)$/` adding `(?:\-|\~)` in between the digits so that will ignore the `-` or `~`.

Comment: @JeffRobertDagala glad to help

Comment: `[-|~]` matches one of the **three** characters: `-`, `|`, or `~`. There are no "or" pipe statements in character classes. Using `[-~]` works just fine.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs oh. thanks, new knowledge for me. just learned regex yesterday :)